# Error inserting into a table where data does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I added a new column to my SQL Server table called `Source`. I want to populate that column with MP during the stored procedure since it does not exist in the original table. I tried the below code several ways and I keep getting an error

> Incorrect Syntax near 'MP'

What am I doing wrong? This worked before and it is not working now. Since the original database is not on this server I have to do an open query it was working till I tried to add this column.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AC_PRODUCT]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[AC_PRODUCT_]
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ARIES_AC_PROPDUCT] (SOURCE, PROPNUM, P_DATE, OIL, GAS)
        SELECT 
            'MP' as SOURCE, PROPNUM, P_DATE, OIL, GAS
        FROM  
            OPENQUERY(ARLPSQL1, 'SELECT DISTINCT 'MP' PROPNUM, P_DATE, OIL, GAS)    
                                 FROM [ARLP_ARIES_MASTER].[dbo].[AC_PRODUCT]');
END
GO
```

Comment: Voting to close as typographical error. You haven't escaped your single quotes in your literal string. `'MP'` should be `''MP''` (and the syntax highlighted very clearly highlights the problem too).

Comment: Ok I changed it now I am getting the following error Invalid column name ''MP'' any ideas?

Comment: Thanks I got it corrected and working now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Ok thanks for the information I was not aware of that.  I will just take out the sp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOU CAN REMOVE 'mp' from openquery since its an static value :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AC_PRODUCT]
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[AC_PRODUCT_];

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[ARIES_AC_PROPDUCT]
            (
                SOURCE
                , PROPNUM
                , P_DATE
                , OIL
                , GAS
            )
        SELECT
            'MP' AS SOURCE
            , PROPNUM
            , P_DATE
            , OIL
            , GAS
        FROM
            OPENQUERY
                (ARLPSQL1, 'SELECT DISTINCT
                                 PROPNUM,
                                P_DATE,
                                OIL,
                                GAS)    
                            FROM [ARLP_ARIES_MASTER].[dbo].[AC_PRODUCT]'
                );
    END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks I got this to work not sure how to close the question?